What is $ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \rm{d}x$?
What is $ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \rm{d}x$ ?

I m not getting any idea for this one . Expecting from the community to share some interesting substitution ideas / tricks .

My try :
$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \rm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{6}} \sqrt{tan\theta + sec\theta}sec^2\theta \rm{d}\theta = \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{6}} \sqrt{\frac{sin\theta+1}{cos\theta}}sec^2\theta\rm{d}\theta = \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{6}} \frac{sec\theta}{\sqrt{cos\theta(1-sin\theta)}}\rm{d}\theta$
No idea how to proceed further or maybe there might be some elegant approaches to it .

In fact, under $t=\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\, \rm{d}x=\int_{1}^{3^{1/4}} t(t+\frac1{t^3}) \,\rm{d}t=\int_{1}^{3^{1/4}}(t^2+t^{-2})\,\rm{d}t=\frac23.$$

Using the integral of inverse functions works too

HINT
Another possible approach
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\sqrt{\sinh(y) + \sqrt{\sinh^{2}(y) + 1}}\mathrm{d}(\sinh(y))\\\\
& = \int\sqrt{\sinh(y) + \cosh(y)}\cosh(y)\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = \int\sqrt{\frac{(e^{y} - e^{-y})}{2} + \frac{(e^{y} + e^{-y})}{2}}\left(\frac{e^{y} + e^{-y}}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Nice solution with a surprise cancellation.

Or one can directly write $x+\sqrt{x^2}+1=e^y$ from the definition of $\sinh^{-1}$.

We can use the substitution $2x=t-\frac{1}{t}$ to het
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} & = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left( t - \frac{1}{t} \right) + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \left( t - \frac{1}{t} \right)^2 + 1}}\\\ \
& = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left( t - \frac{1}{t} \right) + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \left( t^2 - 2 + \frac{1}{t^2} \right) + 1}} \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left( t - \frac{1}{t} \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( t + \frac{1}{t} \right)} = \sqrt{t}.
\end{align*}
Therefore the integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \mathrm{d}x &= \int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{t} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{t^2} \right) \mathrm{d}t \\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}} \left( t^{1/2} + t^{-3/2} \right) \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{2}{3} t^{3/2} - 2t^{-1/2} \right]_{1}^{\sqrt{3}} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left(3\sqrt{3} - 1\right) - \left( \sqrt{3} - 1 \right) \\
&= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}

what made you try 2x = t - 1/t

@uggupuggu See Euler substitution

A more straightforward approach.$$\int^{1\sqrt{3}}_0\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$Substitute $u=\sqrt{x^2+1}+x$ and $du=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+1)dx$, this gives $$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{u^2+1}{2u^{3/2}}du=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\sqrt{3}}_0\frac{u^2+1}{u^{3/2}}du$$then we can substitute $s=\sqrt{u}$ and $ds=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$ so: $$\int^{\sqrt[4]{3}}_1\frac{s^4+1}{s^2}ds=\int^{\sqrt[4]{3}}_1s^2+\frac{1}{s^2}ds=(\frac{s^3}{3}-\frac{1}{s})|_1^{\sqrt[4]{3}}=-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{3}}+1=\frac{2}{3} $$

OP’s direction is correct. However, it is more convenient to put $x=\cot \theta$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\cot \theta+\csc \theta} \csc ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\cot \frac{\theta}{2}} \cdot \frac{\csc ^4 \frac{\theta}{2}}{4 \cot ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}} d \theta \\
& =-\frac{1}{2} \int_{\sqrt{3}}^1 \sqrt{c}\left(\frac{1+c^2}{c^2}\right) d c \quad \textrm{where } c=\cot \frac \theta 2\\
& =-\frac{1}{2} \int_{\sqrt{2}}^1\left(c^{-\frac{3}{2}}+c^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) d c\\&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Footnote:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \cot \theta+\csc \theta=\frac{\cos \theta+1}{\sin \theta}=\frac{2 \cos ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}{2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}}  =\cot \frac{\theta}{2} \\
& \csc ^2 \theta=\frac{1}{4 \sin ^2 \frac{\theta}{2} \cos ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}=\frac{\csc ^4 \frac{\theta}{2}}{4 \cot ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Alternative trig substitution:
$$u=\tan\theta+\sec\theta \implies \theta = 2\arctan\frac{u-1}{u+1} = \frac\pi2-2\arctan u$$
$$\int_0^\tfrac\pi6 \sqrt{\sec\theta+\tan\theta} \, \sec^2\theta \, d\theta = \frac12 \int_\tfrac1{\sqrt3}^1 \left(u^{-1/2} + u^{-5/2}\right) \, du$$

Could you show how to compute $\theta$ from $u=\tan\theta + \sec\theta$?

@PiotrWasilewicz $$u=\sec\theta+\tan\theta=\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{1+2\sin\frac\theta2\cos\frac\theta2}{\cos^2\frac\theta2-\sin^2\frac\theta2} = \frac{1+\tan\frac\theta2}{1-\tan\frac\theta2}=\tan\left(\frac\theta2+\frac\pi4\right)$$You can also set $\sec\theta=\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}$, solve the quadratic for $\tan\theta=\frac{u^2-1}{2u}$, then apply the half-angle identity to get $\tan\frac\theta2=\frac{u-1}{u+1}$.

Exponential substitution makes this integral obvious.
Since
$$e^{\sinh^{-1}{(\frac{x}{a})}}=\frac{1}{a}\left(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x\right),$$
by using the following general transformation formula
$$\int f\left(x, \sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)\, dx = \int f\left(\frac{e^{\theta}-e^{-\theta}}{2}a, \frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}a\right) \frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}a\, d\theta,$$
where $\theta=\sinh^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$ and $x\geq0$, $a>0$, the integral reduces to
$$\begin{aligned}\int\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\,dx&=\int e^{\frac12\theta}\left(\frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}\right)\,d\theta\\&=\frac12 \int (e^{\frac32\theta}+e^{-\frac12\theta})\,d\theta\\&=\frac{e^{2\theta}-3}{3e^{\frac12\theta}}+C\\&=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^2-3}{3\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}+C\end{aligned}$$
Now, applying the limits of integration,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\,dx=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})^2-3}{3\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}}\bigg|_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{2}{3}$$
